# querying MS Access column properties with OleDb

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, select, oledb, database-schema

I'm using OLE and C#.NET to query the schema of a MS Access database.  Specifically, I need to find out whether a particular column is an "identity" column or not.  For SQL Server, I can use:

```
select COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('dbo.tablename'),'columnname','IsIdentity')
```

... but when I invoke this SQL against Access, I get an OleDbException with the following message:

```
Undefined function 'COLUMNPROPERTY' in expression.
```

Searching the archives, it appears there are ways to do this with DAO, but I need to use OLE.  Anyone happen to know how I can do this with OLE?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the schema from the connection, for example:

```
cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Indexes,
                        new Object[] { null, null, null, null, "Table1" });
```

Is the indexes for Table1. One of the fields returned is `PRIMARY_KEY`

See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbschemaguid.columns(v=vs.71)

Answer (score 0):

The same using the GetSchema method.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                                "Data Source=C:\temp\db.mdb;" + 
                                "Persist Security Info=False;")) 
{ 
    con.Open();
    var schema = con.GetSchema("Indexes");
    var col = schema.Select("TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND PRIMARY_KEY = True");
    Console.WriteLine(col[0]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
}
```